# python 2 vs python 3 pd.merge command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The following command works fine if I run python 2

```
df5b = pd.merge(df5a, df5bb, how='outer')
```

However, when I run the same command with the same dfs in python 3, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

My dataframes are very large, I hope that someone can help me out, without giving examples of my dataframes. The command is ok with python 2, so I assume that the problem are not the dataframes, but maybe a change of this command in python 3?

Comment: What is the pandas version you are using with python2 and 3

Comment: I am using version 0.17.1

Comment: this is not doing coerce on mixed types in merging in python3 as i understood from your inputs hence  throwing `ValueError`  on execution. as here are mixed `str` &  `int` or may be `float`. @jezrael  explained it correctly.

Comment: i believe in case we have mixed type we can use concat rather as its not possible with merge. try ... `pd.concat([df5a, df5bb]).dtypes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem some columns are integers in one DataFrame and strings in another with same names.

Simpliest solution is cast all columns to strings:

```
df5b = pd.merge(df5a.astype(str), df5bb.astype(str), how='outer')
```

Another is test dtypes:

```
print (df5a.dtypes)
print (df5bb.dtypes)
```

And convert columns for same, e.g. convert strings columns from list to integers:

```
cols = ['col1','col12','col3']
df5a[cols] = df5a[cols].astype(int)
```

**Sample**:

```
df5a = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4,5],
         'C':[7,8,9,4],
         'F':list('aaab')
})

df5bb = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':['4','5','5'],
         'F':list('aab')
})

df5b = pd.merge(df5a.astype(str), df5bb.astype(str), how='outer')
print (df5b)

   B  C  F
0  4  7  a
1  4  9  a
2  5  8  a
3  5  4  b
```

---

```
print (df5a.dtypes)
B     int64
C     int64
F    object
dtype: object

print (df5bb.dtypes)
B    object
F    object
dtype: object

cols = ['B']
df5bb[cols] = df5bb[cols].astype(int)

df5b = pd.merge(df5a, df5bb, how='outer')
print (df5b)

   B  C  F
0  4  7  a
1  4  9  a
2  5  8  a
3  5  4  b
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I found the column with the problem (thanks to your suggestions to print the dtypes) and converted it. It works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

as i stated in my comment section, coerce is not happening on mixed types(may be `int` , `str` or `float`) hence you can consider concat or  you can convert them as `str` and then merge which jezrael mentioned.

Just to determine types you can see ..

```
>>> pd.concat([df5a, df5bb]).dtypes
B     object
C    float64
F     object
dtype: object

>>> pd.concat([df5a, df5bb])
   B    C  F
0  4  7.0  a
1  5  8.0  a
2  4  9.0  a
3  5  4.0  b
0  4  NaN  a
1  5  NaN  a
2  5  NaN  b
```